# бесконечная сетка для контейнера moveable-react

Tags: reactjs

Я использую плагин `moveable-react` для взаимодействия с элементами. И мне необходимо сделать вот такую бесконечную при прокрутке сетку, как на скриншоте. Сам плагин работает без `canvas`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это возможно?